# link from about to home is not working with navbar

Tags: sass, navbar, parallax

I have made a simple page where the "about" page is having a kind of parallax effect.

As long as you scroll all works fine. Even the navbar works fine, EXCEPT when from "about" to "home". That just won't work.

I have tried to find a solution to this, but I have only found this:

https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/docs/configuration/

https://github.com/mmistakes/jekyll-theme-hpstr/issues/10

https://jekyllrb.com/

If you don't want to follow the links, it all is about Ruby and Jekyll(ruby). Unfortunately, I don't really understand how I should translate that to my code, hence my question here.

I'm using scrollMagic for this project.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <Section id="home">
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </Section>

        <section class="about" id="about">
            <div class="about-title">
                <h1>About</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="about-pages">
                <div>
                    <h2>About 1</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, rerum ex minus atque voluptates, maxime nulla alias aspernatur dicta sequi facere veniam porro voluptatum rem. Ipsa aliquid omnis dignissimos perferendis voluptates suscipit nobis sapiente voluptas, neque harum nisi placeat, obcaecati quisquam ad, nam libero! Dolorem omnis neque ullam earum itaque!.</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h2>About 2</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore dolores, fugiat atque iste, totam suscipit deleniti esse eum soluta culpa fuga dolor in eveniet quis, nam consequuntur beatae ducimus voluptatem veritatis ex nihil obcaecati. Sapiente omnis ipsa rerum ab minima et. Rerum reprehenderit dicta inventore ratione, iusto aut ipsum dignissimos.</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h2>About 3</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo itaque ducimus iste qui sint. Quo aut esse qui blanditiis cupiditate natus dolorem iste corporis facere accusantium vitae ducimus delectus, aliquam cum? Qui velit reprehenderit assumenda quo porro vero dolor libero excepturi cupiditate, accusamus soluta modi maxime natus quae fuga et!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <Section id="projects">
            <h1>Projects</h1>
        </Section>

        <section id="contact">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </section>

    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js"></script>
    <script src="parallax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html .navbar, body .navbar {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #263238;
}

html .navbar ul, body .navbar ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 18px;
  list-style: none;
}

html .navbar ul li a, body .navbar ul li a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #FAFAFA;
}

html #home, body #home {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF176;
  color: #263238;
}

html #about, body #about {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 300vh;
  background-color: #80CBC4;
  color: #FAFAFA;
}

html #about .about-title, body #about .about-title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

html #about .about-pages, body #about .about-pages {
  width: 50%;
}

html #about .about-pages div, body #about .about-pages div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  color: #FAFAFA;
}

html #about .about-pages div p, body #about .about-pages div p {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

html #about .about-pages div:nth-child(1), body #about .about-pages div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #DCE775;
}

html #about .about-pages div:nth-child(2), body #about .about-pages div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #FFEE58;
}

html #about .about-pages div:nth-child(3), body #about .about-pages div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #FFE082;
}

html #projects, body #projects {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #80DEEA;
}

html #contact, body #contact {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #9FA8DA;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

JS:

```
function splitScroll(){
    const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: '200%',
        triggerElement: '.about-title',
        triggerHook: 0
    })
    .setPin('.about-title')
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);
}

splitScroll();
```

Thank you!

Comment: By supplying only SCSS, you require us to compile that. Plus you eliminate a lot of people who do not use SCSS and cannot or will not help you. [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the pointing out, I've changed that now.